# Scrape latitude and longitude locations obtained from Mapbox

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working on a divvy dataset project.

I want to scrape information for each suggestion location and comments provided from here http://suggest.divvybikes.com/.

Am I able to scrape this information from Mapbox? It is displayed on a map so it must have the information somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the page, and logged my network traffic using Google Chrome's Developer Tools. Filtering the requests to view only XHR (XmlHttpRequest) requests, I saw a lot of HTTP GET requests to various REST APIs. These REST APIs return JSON, which is ideal. Only two of these APIs seem to be relevant for your purposes - one is for `places`, the other for `comments` associated with those places. The `places` API's JSON contains interesting information, such as place ids and coordinates. The `comments` API's JSON contains all comments regarding a specific place, identified by its id. Mimicking those calls is pretty straightforward with the third-party `requests` module. Fortunately, the APIs don't seem to care about request headers. The query-string parameters (the `params` dictionary) need to be well-formulated though, of course.

I was able to come up with the following two functions: `get_places` makes multiple calls to the same API, each time with a different `page` query-string parameter. It seems that "page" is the term they use internally to split up all their data into different chunks - all the different places/features/stations are split up across multiple pages, and you can only get one page per API call. The while-loop accumulates all places in a giant list, and it keeps going until we receive a response which tells us there are no more pages. Once the loop ends, we return the list of places.

The other function is `get_comments`, which takes a place id (string) as a parameter. It then makes an HTTP GET request to the appropriate API, and returns a list of comments for that place. This list may be empty if there are no comments.

```
def get_places():
    import requests
    from itertools import count

    api_url = "http://suggest.divvybikes.com/api/places"

    page_counter = count(1)

    places = []

    for page_nr in page_counter:

        params = {
            "page": str(page_nr),
            "include_submissions": "true"
        }

        response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()

        content = response.json()

        places.extend(content["features"])

        if content["metadata"]["next"] is None:
            break

    return places


def get_comments(place_id):
    import requests

    api_url = "http://suggest.divvybikes.com/api/places/{}/comments".format(place_id)

    response = requests.get(api_url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()["results"]


def main():

    from operator import itemgetter

    places = get_places()

    place_id = places[12]["id"]

    print("Printing comments for the thirteenth place (id: {})\n".format(place_id))

    for comment in map(itemgetter("comment"), get_comments(place_id)):
        print(comment)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Printing comments for the thirteenth place (id: 107062)

I contacted Divvy about this five years ago and would like to pick the conversation back up! The Evanston Divvy bikes are regularly spotted in Wilmette and we'd love to expand the system for riders. We could easily have four stations - at the Metra Train Station, and the CTA station, at the lakefront Gillson Park and possibly one at Edens Plaza in west Wilmette.  Please, please, please contact me directly.  Thanks.
>>>
```

For this example, I'm printing all the comments for the 13th place in our list of places. I picked that one because it is the first place which actually has comments (0 - 11 didn't have any comments, most places don't seem to have comments). In this case, this place only had one comment.

---

EDIT - If you wanted to save the place ids, latitude, longitude and comments in a CSV, you can try changing the `main` function to:

```
def main():

    import csv

    print("Getting places...")
    places = get_places()
    print("Got all places.")

    fieldnames = ["place id", "latitude", "longitude", "comments"]

    print("Writing to CSV file...")

    with open("output.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        num_places_to_write = 25

        for place_nr, place in enumerate(places[:num_places_to_write], start=1):
            print("Writing place #{}/{} with id {}".format(place_nr, num_places_to_write, place["id"]))
            writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, [place["id"], *place["geometry"]["coordinates"], [c["comment"] for c in get_comments(place["id"])]])))

    return 0
```

With this, I got results like:

```
place id,latitude,longitude,comments

107098,-87.6711076553,41.9718155716,[]

107097,-87.759540081,42.0121073671,[]

107096,-87.747695446,42.0263916146,[]

107090,-87.6642036438,42.0162096564,[]

107089,-87.6609444613,41.8852953922,[]

107083,-87.6007853815,41.8199433342,[]

107082,-87.6355862613,41.8532736671,[]

107075,-87.6210737228,41.8862644836,[]

107074,-87.6210737228,41.8862644836,[]

107073,-87.6210737228,41.8862644836,[]

107065,-87.6499611139,41.9627251578,[]

107064,-87.6136027649,41.8332984674,[]

107062,-87.7073025402,42.0760990584,"[""I contacted Divvy about this five years ago and would like to pick the conversation back up! The Evanston Divvy bikes are regularly spotted in Wilmette and we'd love to expand the system for riders. We could easily have four stations - at the Metra Train Station, and the CTA station, at the lakefront Gillson Park and possibly one at Edens Plaza in west Wilmette.  Please, please, please contact me directly.  Thanks.""]"
```

In this case, I used the list-slicing syntax (`places[:num_places_to_write]`) to only write the first 25 places to the CSV file, just for demonstration purposes. However, after about the first thirteen were written, I got this exception message:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

So, I'm guessing that the comment-API doesn't expect to receive so many requests in such a short amount of time. You may have to sleep in the loop for a bit to get around this. It's also possible that the API doesn't care, and just happened to timeout.

Comment: Thank You! Very Nice. Is it then possible to export the Log, Lat, and Comments into a csv file?

Comment: @TPConsultant Thanks. I've edited my post, take a look.